# How to ignore build.gradle using lint?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, lint, jslint4java

1. I have added the lint plugin in my JAVA Project. But, it is showing up some warnings in build.gradle file when I am doing clean build.It is not showing any warning or error in the JAVA code. I want to ignore the code in build.gradle and want to focus on the main JAVA code. How can I ignore it?

   ```
   gradleLint.ignore {
   // my build script code that makes the linter suspicious...
   }
   ```

   I can ignore a piece of code using above , but how to ignore build.gradle?
2. Moreover, while generating Lint report using generateGradleLintReport, it is not generating anything.
3. I have the following linting rules:

   `gradleLint.rules = ['dependency-parentheses', 'dependency-tuple']`

   Which other rules to add so that lint gives the compilation errors.

Comment: which IDE are you using

Comment: Why can't you clean up your code to make the linter happy?

Comment: The code is in git. And I am using Jenkins to build the code. @war_Hero

Comment: The linter is showing up just warnings in build.gradle code, which are important. I just can't clean it up. They have to be there in code. @chrylis

Comment: What happens if you put the entire contents of your build.gradle inside `gradleLint.ignore{...}` ?

Comment: Okay. I thought this too but not tried. Kind of inception thingy. Anyways, will try and let you know.